# Problems with Domjudge

Tags: ubuntu

I've installed Domjudge in my machine, including domserver and judgehost.

I followed all instructions of domjudge to install it, and after configuring somthings in Domjudge (at localhost/domjudge/....) and starting a testing contest, I used one account to submit solution to it, but my judgehost (after I started bin/judgedaemon in domjudge's directory) didn't judge and ran into problems:

```html
[...]:~/domjudge/judgehost$ bin/judgedaemon 
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: Judge started on [...] [DOMjudge/5.1.0]
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: Pre-built chroot tree '/chroot/domjudge' not found: using minimal chroot.
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: Not using cgroups. Using cgroups is highly recommended. See the manual for details.
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: Registering judgehost on endpoint http://localhost/domjudge/api
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: Found unfinished judging j12 in my name; given back
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: Judging submission s1 (endpoint default) (t12/p1/cpp), id j13...
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: Working directory: /home/anhldt/domjudge/judgehost/judgings/tuananh-ubtpc/endpoint-default/c2-s1-j13
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: error: unknown executable 'cpp' specified
[...]:~/domjudge/judgehost$
```

```
[Dec 22 22:04:21] judgedaemon[5127]: error: unknown executable 'cpp' specified
```

I don't know what it means and I've looked for it on internet but I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up compilers.To do this just run the following commands in your ubuntu terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install make sudo debootstrap php5-cli php5-curl php5-json procps \
gcc g++ gcj-jre-headless gcj-jdk openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jdk \
ghc fp-compiler
```

Then,

```
cd judgehosts/bin
```

Then ,run judgedaemon

```
./judgedaemon
```

This worked for me. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I've set up compilers before, I also can compile manually by terminal.